# Enumerating vertices with their indices

Tags: python, scripting

This code...

```
def objects_starting( s ):
    return[ obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.name.startswith( s ) ]

def export_all( folder ):
    if not os.path.exists( folder ):
        os.makedirs( folder )

    # G E O M E T R Y (2 files)
    for obj in objects_starting( 'geom' ):
        print( obj.name )
        verts_file = create_file( folder, obj.name + "_verts" )
        faces_file = create_file( folder, obj.name + "_faces" )

        export_geom( verts_file, faces_file, obj )

        verts_file.close( )
        faces_file.close( )

def export_geom( verts_file, faces_file, obj ):

    mesh = obj.data

    verts_file.write( "[points]\n" )
    verts_file.write( "%i\n" % len( mesh.vertices ) )

    for v in mesh.vertices:
        v_world = obj.matrix_world * v.co
        verts_file.write( "%i " % (v+1) )   <-- FAILS HERE
        verts_file.write( "%.16e %.16e %.16e\n" % v_world[:] )
```

fails with:

> TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not MeshVertex

I'm scratching my head because I had something similar working yesterday:

```
def write(filepath):

    meshes = [ob.data for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects if ob.type == 'MESH']
    total_verts = sum(len(me.vertices) for me in meshes)
    total_faces = sum(len(me.polygons) for me in meshes)

    # verts file
    file = open(filepath + ".vert", 'w', encoding="utf8" )

    file.write("[nodes]\n")
    file.write("%i\n" % total_verts)

    for me in meshes:
        for v in me.vertices:
            file.write("%i " % v)
            file.write("%.16e %.16e %.16e\n" % v.co[:])
    file.close()
```

What is going on?  It must be that my new technique for getting a list of meshes doesn't return the right data type, or something.  But I can't see it.

Comment: I suspect (v+1) may be forcing an implicit typecast to integer on v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you try is:

```
verts_file.write("%i " % (v + 1))
```

But `v` refers to a MeshVertex instance. What you need is the `.index` property of the vertex:

```
verts_file.write("%i " % (v.index + 1))
```

Or count yourself:

```
for me in meshes:
    for i, v in enumerate(me.vertices):
        print("%i " % i)
        print("%.16e %.16e %.16e\n" % v.co[:])
```

Comment: I suspected that, but then disregarded it because `file.write("%i " % v)` apparently worked, in the old code. Why didn't this cause the same problem? ...or is it the `+` operator that's giving the error? ...I assumed it was `%i`

Comment: It does not work either way in current Blender, 'cause MeshVertex is not a number and can't be cast to int. It could be implemented (in Python, it would be like `def __int__(self): return self.index`), but why would one want to allow `MeshVertex + int`? If you want the vertex index, then use the vertex index (`v.index`). There's nothing wrong with `+` or `%i`, but the code is incorrect.

Comment: Sure, I understand that it's a type problem. I didn't realize that there was a MeshVertex.index so it was just a suspicion. Regardless, all I was saying is that because `+` complains for `MeshVertex + int`, it seems like `"%i " MeshVertex` should ALSO complain. Maybe it just doesn't, but I thought you might know why.

Comment: `"%i" % bpy.context.object.data.vertices[0]` will complain about the type as well: `TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not MeshVertex`

Answer (score -1):

You're adding 1 to `v` in `verts_file.write( "%i " % (v+1) )` but the `+` operator is expecting `v` to be an integer, not a MeshVertex, which is why it didn't fail the first time (you weren't adding to it).

As CoDEmanX states, you need to operate on `v.index` to get the vertex's index.

(`+` was expecting the integer, not `%i` as I claimed before)